# Divergence-free Gaussian vector field with given mean magnitude and correlation function

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

My general question is how to construct an isotropic random vector field $\vec f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ with a given mean magnitude $\mathbb{E}[\|\vec f(\vec x)\|]=\mu$ and with vector magnitudes and direction correlated up to some length scales $l$ (beyond which the correlation goes to zero). I prefer a construction satisfying $\nabla \cdot \vec f=0$, but a construction without that condition is already interesting.

More precisely, we are given a vector $\vec{\mu}$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$  and a matrix-valued correlation function $C: \mathbb{R^3} \times \mathbb{R^3} \to M_3(\mathbb{R})$ which is isotropic, i.e $C(\vec v,\vec w)=C(\|\vec v-\vec w\|)$. One may define a Gaussian Process $f(\vec x) \sim GP(\vec{\mu},C)$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\vec f(\vec x)]=\vec\mu$ and $Cov(\vec f(v),\vec f(w))=C(\vec v,\vec w)$. I believe that constructions of such a random field $f$ are known. The equivalent problem for a scalar field $f$ seems well-studied: one can first draw the field in Fourier space by normalizing a white noise field with the appropriate power spectrum $P(k)$, and then transform back to real space. Here I am looking for a simple procedure for $\mathbb{R}^3$; I think this is known but I haven't found a clear description anywhere.

**Question**: How can one generate such a random field $f$ with a mean vector of zero ($\vec{\mu}=\vec 0$), and a mean *magnitude* of $\mu$ ($\mathbb{E}[\|\vec f(\vec x)\|]=\mu$)? And what if we also impose $\nabla \cdot \vec f=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One construction uses that divergence free fields are precisely the rotation fields:

Choose any isotropic matrix valued covariance function $C':\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}_{\ge0}$. Then, the push forward $\nabla\times g=GP(0,\nabla\times C'\times\nabla)$ of the Gaussian process $g=GP(0,C')$ is such an isotropic covariance function with divergence free realizations.

The details of the construction of the covariance $C:=\nabla\times C'\times\nabla$ are that the rotation operator from the left is applied to the first argument and the rotation operator from the left is applied to the second argument.

If you include a factor in $C'$, you can fit it afterwards to get the intended mean magnitude. If you choose $C'$ "general enough", than $C$ is "general enough".

(Shameless self-promotion:) See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09197 (or https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.00818).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am bit confused by your operator $C:=\nabla\times C'\times\nabla$. Can you kindly be more explicit on how this is defined?

Comment: Also, your paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.09197.pdf cites https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:606538/FULLTEXT01.pdf, which, in a similar vein describes how to generate a divergence-free Gaussian  field with given correlation length $l$ and (vector) mean value $\mathbf{\mu}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}$, by using a matrix-valued correlation function $C(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$ with correlation length $l$ such that realizations are necessarily divergence-free. The only missing condition here for my problem is to impose the mean magntude.  I'm wondering if their kernel can be adapted for this?

Comment: Yes, my operator $C$ follows the same construction as diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:606538/FULLTEXT01.pdf.
If you multiply $C'$ by a positive factor $\sigma^2$, the construction is still valid. Then $C$ is also multiplied by $\sigma^2$ and hence the "mean magnitude" (however you define it) should also be increased by $\sigma$.

Comment: thanks for this elegant construction. Sorry, my knowledge of Gaussian random vector fields is very limited. You seem to be suggesting that when the mean vector $\vec{\vec{\mu}}$ is set to $\vec{0}$, the mean magnitude, which I define as the (constant over space) expectation value of $\vec{f}(\vec{x})$, is uniquely determined by the correlation function $C$. Is this true and if so, how might I calculate the mean magntitude in terms of $C$? Thanks for your time.

Comment: forgetting the divergence free condition and condition on the mean magntitude, would you kindly point me towards a reference on methods for generating Gaussian random vector fields. This review https://repository.kaust.edu.sa/bitstream/handle/10754/656527/final%20version%20(1).pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=n gives a survey of such methods but only for scalar fields.

Comment: The variance of an isotropic Gaussian random field is given by its covariance function. If you scale the covariance function, you scale the variance. In machine learning, this is often called the signal variance. From the variance of a Gaussian, you can simply compute everything else you need in term of magnitued, I guess.
A lot of this, including sampling, is described in the book by Rasmussen and Williams.